# JSTL forEach and if code not executing properly

Tags: html, jsp, loops, jstl, jsp-tags

I wrote this code for an assignment but it appears to be not executing properly.

```
<c:if test="${counter<fn:length(passangername[status.index])}"> 
                <c:redirect url="confirmbooking.jsp" >
                    <c:param name="error" value="Invalid Data. Please try again!"/>
                </c:redirect>
        </c:if>
```

I am printing the counter values to check if the loop is working fine or not and during the first iteration, it seems to work fine but the counter value is not being printed in the second iteration and so forth. I know the second iteration takes place because I can see the other stuff printing. As a result the "if" part at the end is not working which is why it needs to be fixed. NOTE: everything else besides this is working fine. What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

ADDITIONAL NOTE: The code is working fine if all inputs are only alphabets for instance, Saurav or John but if the second input is a combination of alphabets and numbers, the code does not work.

```
<c:set var="alphaupper" value="${['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']}"/>
<c:set var="alphalower" value="${['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' ']}"/>

<c:forEach begin="0" end="${param.looper-1}" varStatus="status">
        <c:set var="counter" value="0"/>
        <c:out value="${passangername[status.index]}"/> &nbsp; <c:out value="length: ${fn:length(passangername[status.index])}"/><br>

                <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(passangername[status.index])}" step="1">
                    <c:forEach var="j" begin="0" end="${fn:length(alphaupper)}" step="1">
                        <c:if test="${fn:substring(passangername[status.index], i, i + 1)==alphaupper[j] or fn:substring(passangername[status.index], i, i + 1)==alphalower[j]}">
                            <c:set var="counter" value="${counter=counter+1}"/> 
                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:forEach>

        <c:out value="counter: ${counter}"/><br> 

            <c:if test="${counter<fn:length(passangername[status.index])}"> 
                    <c:redirect url="confirmbooking.jsp" >
                        <c:param name="error" value="Invalid Data. Please try again!"/>
                    </c:redirect>
            </c:if> 

        <c:set var="records" value="${records=records+1}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It's about time to learn servlets: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info Doing business and HTTP controller logic like this in a JSP file makes no sense.

Comment: I appreciate your input and I will definitely work on learning servlets but this project requires me to do it using JSTL (it's for college). So, I have to do it like this. Thanks.